# Why Calling a Number With Cell Name Comes Empty NO?

Tags: excel, vba

If I call

```
=GetElementByRegex(A3,"placeholder=""(.*?)"">")
```

its working, but when I want to take number or another code

```
A2=`https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/taiwantrade.com/`

=GetElementByRegex(A2,"<!-- Alexa web traffic metrics are available via our API at http://aws.amazon.com/awis -->(.*?)</strong>")
```

its comes Empty. I dont know why. I am new one

The code I am using.

```
Public Function GetElementByRegex(url As String, reg As String)
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResult As Object
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regEx.Pattern = reg
    regEx.Global = True
    If regEx.Test(XMLHTTP.ResponseText) Then
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(XMLHTTP.ResponseText)
        If IsMissing(index) Then
            GetElementByRegex = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetElementByRegex = matches(index).SubMatches(0)
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    GetElementByRegex = ""
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following RegEx: https://regex101.com/r/EQBjSC/1

```
=GetElementByRegex(A2,"<!-- Alexa web traffic metrics are available via our API at http:\/\/aws\.amazon\.com\/awis -->\n(.*?)<\/strong>")
```

Note that you have to escape special characters like `/` and `.` with a backslash `\`